# SQL query difficulty

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a more succinct way to write the below code?

```
$myQuery = "
   SELECT * FROM `rooms`
    WHERE (
              `Facility1` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility2` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility3` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility4` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility5` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility6` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility7` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility8` IN ($inList)
           OR `Facility9` IN ($inList)
           ) AND `Location` LIKE '".$Location."%'
             AND `RoomType` LIKE '".$RoomType."%'
    ORDER BY CONVERT(`Capacity`, SIGNED)
";
```

Comment: Do you have 9 `Facility` columns? Why?

Comment: It's a database that I've been given to work with sorry

Comment: The obvious answer here is to normalize by making a facilities table linking room_id to facility - is that not a viability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make this more compact, you could write code to build the query for you:

```
$fac_array=array();
for ($i=1;$i<=9;$i++){
    array_push($fac_array, "Facility$i in (\$inlist)");
}
$facility_condition = implode(" OR ",$fac_array);
$full_query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE (".$facility_condition.") AND....";
```

But really, the issue with a query like the one you show is not about the code, but about the structure of your data model, which is not "normalized".

"Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency.". You have 9 "Facility" fields, and this gives you three problems (not mentioning the difficulty of building queries):

1. If you ever have more than 9 facilities, you need to change your database schema and all your queries.
2. If you sometimes use less than 9 facilities for each record, you're wasting space.
3. If you change a facility's information, you'd have to go through your database and change the data in each record that contains it.

The issue here is that the "Facility" should be an "entity" in itself, and as such, should be contained in its own table; other tables would just "refer" to the canonical Facility table. This avoids the problems I mention through a number of well-known relational database techniques.

I sugges you read up on database normalization and consider reworking your database's structure to conform to having a Facility table, and (as I deduce you will need from looking at the query) an "intermediate" facility_room table which would map facilities to rooms.

Here's a place to get started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

and here: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/

Comment: The question was originally about the ROomType and Location not being honored, I thought it was because of lack of parentheses, but I see the question has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nine different columns for Facility (Facility1..9), I bet your real issue is with you table structure.

Do you have any way to convert you TABLE into two or more tables that are based on rows, such as

```
TABLE rooms (id int, Location varchar, RoomType varchar, , ...)
TABLE facilities (id int, name varchar)
TABLE facility_rooms (facility_id int, room_id int)
```

Then you could use a JOIN to do your query in little to no time.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the conditional programmatically with a loop in PHP.

But within the scope of the SQL query itself then — assuming that `$inList` looks like `a,b,c` — no, you can't improve it. You're slaved to this poor, non-normalized database design that you've said you've been given.

Fortunately your query is not *too* much of a monstrosity the way it is, unless `$inList` is surprisingly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If all the items that can ever appear in `($inList)` are already stored in a column (named `facility_name`) in another table (named `facility`), then you could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT 
      r.* 
FROM 
      rooms AS r
  JOIN
      facility AS f
    ON
      f.facility_name IN ($inList)
    AND 
      f.facility_name IN (Facility1, Facility2, ..., Facility9)
WHERE
      r.Location LIKE '".$Location."%'
  AND 
      r.RoomType LIKE '".$RoomType."%'
GROUP BY
      r.PK                    --- the Primary Key of table `rooms`
ORDER BY 
      CONVERT(r.Capacity, SIGNED)
```

or:

```
SELECT 
      r.* 
FROM 
      rooms AS r
WHERE
      EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM facility AS f
               WHERE f.facility_name IN ($inList)
                 AND f.facility_name IN (r.Facility1, ..., r.Facility9)
             )
  AND
      r.Location LIKE '".$Location."%'
  AND 
      r.RoomType LIKE '".$RoomType."%'
ORDER BY 
      CONVERT(r.Capacity, SIGNED)
```